# How to save a text file without having to enter file name every time?

Tags: java

Hi all I am creating a simple text editor as a project and I have hit a snag when it comes to saving the content typed as a file. I can save the file using the Save As principle with a dialog box prompting the user to enter a filename.

The problem I am having is implementing the Save so that it saves to the file that is opened without having to go to the dialog box each time, like it would if someone did Ctrl+S. Anyone have any ideas how I would implement this feature?

Here's some of my code:

```
JMenuItem saveFile = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Save") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser();
        File filename = save.getSelectedFile();
        if(opened == false && saved == false) {
            save.showSaveDialog(null);
            int confirmationResult;
            if(filename.exists()) {
            confirmationResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(getParent(), "Replace existing file?");
                if(confirmationResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    saveFile(filename);                     
                }
            } else {
                saveFile(filename);
            }
        } else {
            saveFile(filename);
        }
    }
});
saveFile.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
saveFile.setEnabled(true);
```

save method:

```
private void saveFile(File filename) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        writer.write(textArea.getText());
        writer.close();
        saved = true;
        editorWindow.setTitle("JavaText - " + filename.getName());
    } catch (IOException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Store of file name somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store the opened File object somewhere in your application you can then just pass that into your saveFile method on a key press using a KeyListener or KeyAdapter. Without seeing more of the application it's hard to tell where would be best to put it, but if you just store it in a variable somewhere you can refer back to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Store the file name somewhere
2. `if(nameOfFile != null)` then don't show the dialog box and go to save method
3. `else` show dialog box and call the save method

That's what I would do

Answer (score 0):

The following program shows the implementation of 'Save' & 'Save as' functionality for text editors. Running it will shows a **JFrame** with a **JTextArea** , save **JButton** & save as **JButton**.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private boolean alreadySaved = false;
    private BufferedWriter bw;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;
    private JTextArea jta;
    private File file;
    private JButton save;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JButton saveAs;

    public MyFrame() {
        initComponents();

        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (!alreadySaved) {
                    int response = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(getParent());
                    file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        writeFile();
                        alreadySaved = true;
                    }
                } else
                    writeFile();
            }

        });

        saveAs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int response = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(getParent());
                file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    writeFile();
                    alreadySaved = true;
                }
            }
        });

    } // END of Constructor

    public void writeFile() {
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            bw.write(jta.getText());
            bw.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        saveAs = new JButton("Save as");
        jta = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
        save = new JButton("Save");
        mainPanel.add(save);
        mainPanel.add(saveAs);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(jta);
        this.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```